# Launch apps full screen

Tags: macos, fullscreen

I quite like using full-screen apps on OSX Mavericks (Safari, iTunes, Mail, etc).  I'd like all apps that are capable of running full-screen to launch in full-screen mode automatically, instead of me having to press Ctrl-Cmd-F each time, is that possible?

Comment: My apps always launch in full screen, if I hadn't closed all windows last time I quit them.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about it but I'd an old iMac which saw different OS X versions. When that iMac first met with full-screen apps, apps always started full-screen when closed like that and still does on Mavericks. But on my newer MacBook Air, which I acquired with Mountain Lion and then upgraded to Mavericks, it doesn't happen like that. Therefore, I happen to believe that it's an old preference on my iMac which can't be replicated on newer models.

Comment: This is a big problem. Many apps will re-open in full screen if quitted full screen. Safari does not. Chrome does not. There is a Chrome hack that does it, but I can't find any way to do it in Safari. Anyone got more info for this question?

Comment: A bit of a follow up - this seems to work when using iTunes, but not with the Calendar App, Pages, Etc.

Answer (score 10):

You can use automator to create an application that will launch the application that you want to open in full screen and run an apple script. The script can perform a keystroke to run the shortcut for full screen.

Launch Automator, Choose Application, Drag "Launch Application" from library and choose desired app, Drag "Apple Script" from library, enter apple script (check with specific app for correct keystroke), this works for chrome

here is the script for google chrome fullscreen app:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
    delay 2
```

`tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}
end tell`

Screenshot

[[image: Automator Screenshot[1]]

Link with tutorial to create Automator Full screen application
https://youtu.be/5L5ikafzCzI

Answer (score 5):

I realized the answer to this question well long after I had the problem. I kept trying to use several work arounds until I realized that feature hadn't been removed, but rather rolled into a different set of features.

Most full-screen apps don't remain open because it's a type of window state. By default, under General, the setting "Close windows when quitting an app" is turned on, which means the window you have saved will be closed and return to it's default state.

To retain full-screen, or your previous window preferences, you need to turn off this setting!

[image: General Preferences Window Setting]

Comment: thanks, this helped with a few apps, though not all

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea that that was even  off. There were several settings in that pane that I thought I had changed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I called Mac support about the issue, and it seems in Yosemite this feature has been since removed in general. However there are *some* apps that still function this way. One of them being iTunes (which opens in full screen mode).

It was suggested, to get the functionality of a full screen app, after quitting, is to assign an app to a new desktop, and maximize it (press the option key + clicking on green). It will always open that desktop in full screen.

Answer (score 2):

```applescript
set MyApps to {"Google Chrome", "Skype", "Finder"}
repeat with MyApp in MyApps
    tell application MyApp
        activate
        delay 3
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process MyApp
            set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 to true
            delay 3
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting the code! Good use of AppleScript - perhaps explain how a new user would get that code to run (or better link to osxautomation / apple help on Script Editor)