# Automatically make QuickTime fullscreen when opened

Tags: macos, quicktime

Question above. I often use QuickTime for watching video tutorials, but I want to be able to start it in fullscreen automatically.

Comment: I updated the _code_ in my answer since you accepted it, so please review it again.  I added a second `delay` statement as the transition from opening to full screen and playing will look better.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, I did think it was much too jittery. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**QuickTime Player** doesn't have a **Preferences...** *menu command* like other applications do, nor does it have a *com.apple.quicktime.plist* file to manipulate. Therefore there isn't anything you can do directly, however here is a workaround of sorts.

Note that this workaround requires changing the *default* application for *file types*, e.g. *.mov*, you'd normally open directly with **QuickTime Player** to the application created herein, called: **QTP Full Screen.app**

Using **Automator** create a new *Application* and add a **Run Shell Script** *Action*.

Change: **Pass input: [to stdin]** *to* **[as argument]**

Add the following *code*:

```
if [[ ! -z $1 ]]; then

    open -a "QuickTime Player" "$1"

    osascript -e 'tell application "QuickTime Player" to activate' \
              -e 'delay 1.5' \
              -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "f" using command down' \
              -e 'delay 1.5' \
              -e 'tell application "QuickTime Player" to play front document'
fi
```

[image]

Save it as an *Application* named: **QTP Full Screen**

In order for **QTP Full Screen** to be the *global default app* for, e.g. *.mov*, files you'd open in QuickTime Player you'll have to use the **Default Apps** Preference Pane, [RCDefaultApp by Rubicode](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) to change which application opens a given Extension.

Install **RCDefaultApp** and then in **System Preferences** > **Default Apps** select the **Extensions** tab and scroll down to ***mov*** and then change the **Default Application:** *to*: **QTP Full Screen**

Now then you double-click *.mov* files in **Finder** or accessing them from **Spotlight** the **QTP Full Screen** application will open the target file in **Quick Time Player**, set **View** to **Full Screen** and start playing the file.

Note: If you do not want it to automatically start playing the file then remove the line of *code*, the one that has "play front document" in it.

If you need modify other *default* methods of file types, Apps, URLs, UTIs, etc. the **Default Apps** Preference Pane, [RCDefaultApp by Rubicode](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/), is a great utility for it.

To make the **QTP Full Screen.app** application bundle look better in the Applications folder you can copy and paste the **QuickTime Player.app** application icon from its **Get Info** *sheet* to the icon of the **Get Info** *sheet* for **QTP Full Screen.app**.

Note:  The *value* of the `delay` statements can be adjusted in *seconds* and or *decimal fractions* thereof, as might be necessary on any given system to account for its processing speed.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply press the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>  <kbd>F</kbd> key as a shortcut to go to full screen. I don't think that Quicktime has any settings that support this feature natively, and it's not too difficult to press the shortcut every time you watch a video.

Otherwise you could make an an automator as suggested here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208399/183022